# Replace a row in Pandas Dataframe with NaN if an ID value in that row isn't a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, nan

I apologize for the potentially confusing title, but I will try to explain my situation as best I can.

Let's say I have a hypothetical Dataframe `df`, which has an `id` column and is arranged like...

```
  time  id   x    y
  1.0    0   5    9 
  2.0    1   6    8
  3.0    2   7    7
  4.0    1   8    6
```

Now lets say I want only the data from rows with `df[id] = 1`, but instead of dropping the other rows I fill it with `NaN` like this...

```
  time  id   x    y
  1.0    0   NaN  NaN
  2.0    1   6    8
  3.0    2   NaN  NaN
  4.0    1   8    6
```

Note that I specifically want to *keep* the `time` and `id` columns, just change the values of `x` and `y` to `NaN` for any rows that don't have the `id` column set to `1`

My first attempt was to use `DataFrame.groupby()`, but this leads to any rows without the specific `id` value being dropped entirely, which I don't want. My first instinct is to go into `df` row by row, checking the id column, and changing the values to `NaN` manually if `id != 1`, but this seems like a very cumbersome and un-Pythonic way of doing this.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple selection with a boolean mask:

```
df.loc[df['id'].ne(1), ['x', 'y']] = float('nan')
```

Output:

```
   time  id    x    y
0   1.0   0  NaN  NaN
1   2.0   1  6.0  8.0
2   3.0   2  NaN  NaN
3   4.0   1  8.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import NAN
df.loc[df['id']!=1 , ['x','y']] = NAN
```